# Inserir duas imagens

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Existe alguma forma de fazer upload de duas imagens ao mesmo tempo e no final do processo ela ser tipo uma marca d´água pra um background ?

Comment: Posta o código que você tem!

Comment: Esse post vai te ajudar bastante https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%C3%83o-fazer-perguntas/